# Property of type X may not have default value

Tags: php

I want to define typed classes in php, following the recent type features (to be used as part of https://github.com/rutek/dataclass). The below returns the error "Property of type CustomType may not have default value" - how do I define CustomType such that it is allowed a default value? Notably this occurs no matter what default value is placed here.

```php
class CustomType {
    public static string $item;
    public function __construct(string $item) {
        $this->item = $item;
    }
}

class NewClass {
    public CustomType $test = CustomType("1");
}
```

Edit: Based on answers I have modified my question such that the default value is of type CustomType. What I didn't specify is I would like to achieve this by modifying CustomType rather than NewClass. This should be possible, as default types like int have this behaviour:

```php
class NewClass {
    public int $test = 1;;
}
```

Edit 2: I discovered the Dataclass library uses a built-in function to obtain the default values: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdefaultproperties.php
This is at least one piece of the puzzle! It's the validation of these defaults that I wish to edit.

Edit 3: The lack of static classes in php means I think what I'm trying to do may not be possible in this way - I've edited the original question to the "ideal world" syntax

Answer (score 1):

First, in this assignment:

```
public CustomType $test = array("item"=>"testitem");
```

the left part is of `CustomType` type so it expects some instance of `CustomType`, but the right one is `array`.

Then, it's literally may not have the default value. To adjust it via the Dataclass library you should use the constructor like:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Make sure the path here is correct

use function Rutek\Dataclass\transform;

class CustomType {
    public string $item;
}

class NewClass {

    public CustomType $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = transform('CustomType', array('item' => 'testitem'));
    }
}

// Check the result
$c = new NewClass;
var_dump($c);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I have modified the question to be more specific based on your answer